# failsafe not working with wiremock integration tests

Tags: integration-testing, wiremock, maven-failsafe-plugin

I am using a simple spring application with unit and integration tests. 
I am trying to use wiremock for integrated tests but when I execute `mvn failsafe:integration-test` goal the result is `Tests run: 0`.

My pom.xml configuration is:

```
...
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
  <artifactId>wiremock</artifactId>
  <version>2.25.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
...
<build>
  ..
  <plugins>
    ..
    <plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>**/*ITTest</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    ..
  </plugins>
  ..
</build>
```

And the wiremock test:

```
public class WireMockITTest {

    private static final String ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:8089/sample/";
    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    @Rule
    public WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule(8089);

    @Test
    public void shouldGetSuccess() throws URISyntaxException {
        URI getEndpoint = new URI(ENDPOINT + 1234);
        ResponseEntity<Sample> responseEntity = restTemplate
                .getForEntity(getEndpoint, Sample.class);

        verify(getRequestedFor(urlEqualTo("/sample/" + 1234)));
        assertTrue(responseEntity.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful());
    }
}
```

Can you help me?
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem when I removed junit dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
  <version>5.5.2</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Thks!